# Why do Google fonts look crisp on google's site but not on mine

Tags: css, fonts, font-face, webfonts

I'm using josefin sans font from Google fonts. It looks crisp and sharp on their website and consistently so for all browsers. But when I import the fonts to my site via linking to provided css file , they look thin and blurry. I know about some fixes you can do, but they don't work consistently. why does this happen? Does putting these fonts locally help ?

Comment: What format are they in?

Comment: What is the CSS that you are using to import the font files?

Comment: i import them using the google provided <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Sans:100,300,400,600,700" />  and i use them using something like font-size: 11px;
         font-family: "Josefin Sans";
         font-weight: 300;
         font-style: normal;
         color: white;
         text-align: center;
         text-transform: uppercase;

Comment: @nuway I'm not sure but I think you need a "//" or "http://" before the `href` cause it might be pointing to a local file instead of the Google Fonts server.

Answer (score 0):

Each font (or almost each) hash a few "sub-fonts" if you will which are slight variations of the original font. Make sure you select the one you really want. Look at the variations:
[Josefin Sans](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TuW7N.jpg)

Comment: Yes. I was under impression you can only set the font weight. Can I set the light, regular or semi-bold attributes, and if so, with what CSS property?

Comment: @nuway Those are one and the same. You basically choose the 'weight' that you would like to choose as those. In this case it's: 300, 400, and 600 respectively.

Comment: @EstebanFelix Google Fonts default settings when choosing a font is 300 I believe so he might not have selected the correct one.

Comment: @nuway Well you can also set bold, italic and so on but that is within `familiy-font` property in css

Comment: so you're saying its font-family: "Josefin Sans Regular"; font-weigth:400; to get the font listed under regular-400? btw, the fonts dont look too good in your screenshot

Comment: @nuway Did you also make sure to include the fonts as being loaded? By default I believe only 300 is included which could explain the lack of anti-aliasing.

Comment: @nuway well it's a screen shot.... It was only to show which ones are included where. And no, you use the same way you just set `bold` or `italic` in the appropriate place.

Comment: @ViruZX what is the appropriate place? can you show me exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Did you make sure to include all of the needed font files?

Your CSS link should look something like this:

`<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Sans:300,400,600' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>`

Comment: Thats not an `@import`, its a `<link>`

Comment: @ViruZX sorry, I meant `link`. You are technically correct, the best kind of correct.